# How do I find $\gcd(p,q)$ and $\mathrm{lcm}(p,q)$ by using syzygies?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let us introduce the setting and recall some definitions.

**Setting**: We are in a UFD polynomial ring $K[x]$ with $p,q \in K[x]$.

**Definition**: Given a finitely generated $R$-module $M$ (where $R$ is a  commutative ring) and a set $\{z_1,...,z_n\}$ of generators, a *syzygy* of $M$ is an element $(a_1,...,a_n) \in R^n$ for which $a_1z_1+\cdots+a_nz_n=0$.

Now how can one obtain the gcd and lcm from the syzygies of $p,q$? That is, $\mathrm{Syz}(p,q)$? To clarify, we may consider $I = (p,q)$.

Comment: Your definition of syzygy is for a module, yet your last line refers to the syzygy of polynomials. Would you care to remind (us and yourself) how the definition extends?

Comment: Also isn't the zero-tuple $(0,\cdots 0)$ a syzygy for every module over a commutative ring?

Comment: No consider $I=(p,q)$, and no $0$ sygyzy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $R=K[X]$.
$\mathrm{Syz}(p,q)=\{(a,b)\in R^2:ap+bq=0\}$ is an $R$-submodule of $R^2$.
Since $R$ is PID, $\mathrm{Syz}(p,q)$ is also a free $R$-module (of rank $1$). (Why?) Then $\mathrm{Syz}(p,q)=R(u,v)$.
In particular, $(-q,p)=d(u,v)$ for some $d\in R$.
We claim that $d=\gcd(p,q)$.
Obviously $d\mid p$ and $d\mid q$.
Now suppose $\delta\mid p$ and $\delta\mid q$. Then $p=\delta p_1$ and $q=\delta q_1$. Since $(-q_1,p_1)\in\mathrm{Syz}(p,q)$ we get $(-q_1,p_1)=s(u,v)$, so $-q_1=su$ and $p_1=sv$. This leads to $p=\delta sv$ and $-q=\delta su$, and hence $d=\delta s$, that is, $\delta\mid d$.

Comment: Thank you, once my rep increases i will provide up vote.

Answer (score 0):

$K[x]$ is an euclidean domain, hence you compute the gcd of two elements by using the euclidean algorithm.

Comment: However, the question asks for a different approach.

Comment: Thank you, once my rep increases i will provide up vote.